# AWS IAM role creation via Windows CLI

Tags: json, amazon-web-services

I'm currently working on an AWS course, and have been using the Windows CLI in order to setup demo infrastructure in my AWS VPC.   I was attempting to create a role called "bastion-role" via using the following command:

```
aws iam create-role --role-name bastion-role --assume-role-policy-document file://role-policy.json
```

but it yields this error:

> Error parsing parameter `--assume-role-policy-document`: Unable to
> load paramfile file://role-policy.json: [Errno 2] No such file or
> directory: 'role-policy.json'

I'm assuming it's having a problem referencing the local directory that I'm currently in.  I've attempted the following troubleshooting measures:

- Not using the `file://` part and just the name 'role-policy.json'.  This didn't work
- Trying to reference the local directory: `file://c:\role-policy-json`
- Tried a relative path: `file://../role-policy.json`
- Tried using 3 forward slashes: `file:///role-policy.json`
- Tried using 3 forward slashes and local directory: `file:///c:\role-policy.json`

Unfortunately, none of these combinations have worked.  I'm assuming I'm missing something, but I can't figure it out.  If someone could shed some light on this problem, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-parameters-file.html suggests second option should work. Where's the json file? What directory? Are you aware that there seems to be a typo in your second option? (`c:\role-policy-json` instead of `c:\role-policy.json`)

Answer (score 1):

Probably its too late to provide this answer, but the right way to execute this command is like this:

`aws iam --region us-east-2 create-role --role-name <YOUR_ROLE_NAME> --assume-role-policy-document file://C:\Users\<USERNAME>\FULL\PATH\TO\file_containing_policy.json`

After successful execution you should see something like this:

```
{
    "Role": {
        "Path": "/",
        "RoleName": "YOUR_ROLE_NAME",
        "RoleId": "AROXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:role/YOUR_ROLE_NAME",
        "CreateDate": "2020-11-17T04:53:35+00:00",
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [
                {
                    "Sid": "",
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Principal": {
                        "Service": "<SERVICE>.amazonaws.com"
                    },
                    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the additional information, I appreciate it!  :-D